# C# application crashes after sending xml through outlook mail

Tags: c#

C# application crashes after sending xml through outlook mail. Also it requires outlook to be closed while sending mail.Using OUTLOOK 2010. It works fine with lower versions.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Amdocs.Infra.Controls
{
   public class OutlookWrapper
   {
     public OutlookWrapper ()
     {
       outlookType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID ("Outlook.Application", true);
       outlookObject = Activator.CreateInstance (outlookType);
       namespaceMAPI = outlookType.InvokeMember ("GetNamespace", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, outlookObject, new object [] {"MAPI"});
       namespaceMAPIType = namespaceMAPI.GetType ();
       namespaceMAPIType.InvokeMember ("Logon", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, namespaceMAPI, new object [] {null, null, true, false});
     }
#endregion

#region ~OutlookWrapper ()
~OutlookWrapper ()
{
  namespaceMAPIType.InvokeMember ("Logoff", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, namespaceMAPI, new object [] {});
}
#endregion

#region SendMail

#region public void SendMail (bool modal, string toValue)
public void SendMail (bool modal, string toValue)
{
  SendMail (modal, toValue, String.Empty);
}
#endregion
#region public void SendMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue)
public void SendMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue)
{
  SendMail (modal, toValue, subjectValue, String.Empty);
}
#endregion
#region public void SendMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue)
public void SendMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue)
{
  SendMail (modal, toValue, subjectValue, bodyValue, null);
}
#endregion
#region public void SendMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue, string[] attachments)
public void SendMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue, string[] attachments)
{
  CreateNewMailItem (toValue, subjectValue, bodyValue, attachments);
  outlookMailItemType.InvokeMember ("Send", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, outlookMailItem, new object [] {modal});
}
#endregion

#endregion

#region NewMail

#region public void NewMail ()
public void NewMail ()
{
  NewMail (true);
}
#endregion
#region public void NewMail (bool modal)
public void NewMail (bool modal)
{
  NewMail (modal, String.Empty);
}
#endregion
#region public void NewMail (bool modal, string toValue)
public void NewMail (bool modal, string toValue)
{
  NewMail (modal, toValue, String.Empty);
}
#endregion
#region public void NewMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue)
public void NewMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue)
{
  NewMail (modal, toValue, subjectValue, String.Empty);
}
#endregion
#region public void NewMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue)
public void NewMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue)
{
  NewMail (modal, toValue, subjectValue, bodyValue, null);
}
#endregion
#region public void NewMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue, string[] attachments)
public void NewMail (bool modal, string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue, string[] attachments)
{
  CreateNewMailItem (toValue, subjectValue, bodyValue, attachments);
  outlookMailItemType.InvokeMember ("Display", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, outlookMailItem, new object [] {modal});
}
#endregion

#endregion

#region private void CreateNewMailItem (string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue, string[] attachments)
private void CreateNewMailItem (string toValue, string subjectValue, string bodyValue, string[] attachments)
{
  outlookMailItem = outlookType.InvokeMember ("CreateItem", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, outlookObject, new object [] {null});
  if (outlookMailItem == null) throw new ApplicationException (StringsManager.GetString("Cannot create outlook mail item."));

  outlookMailItemType = outlookMailItem.GetType ();
  if (outlookMailItemType == null) throw new ApplicationException (StringsManager.GetString("Cannot get outlook mail item type."));

  outlookMailItemType.InvokeMember ("To",      BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, outlookMailItem, new object [] {toValue});
  outlookMailItemType.InvokeMember ("Subject", BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, outlookMailItem, new object [] {subjectValue});
  outlookMailItemType.InvokeMember ("Body",    BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, outlookMailItem, new object [] {bodyValue});

  if (attachments != null)
  {
    object attachmentsObject = outlookMailItemType.InvokeMember ("Attachments", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, outlookMailItem, new object [] {});
    if (attachmentsObject == null) throw new ApplicationException (StringsManager.GetString("Cannot get outlook attachments property."));

    System.Type attachmentsType = attachmentsObject.GetType ();
    if (attachmentsType == null) throw new ApplicationException (StringsManager.GetString("Cannot get outlook attachments property type."));

    int bodyLength = bodyValue.Length;

    /*
     * We do not need this since we have the original text message
     * 
    object bodyObject = outlookMailItemType.InvokeMember ("Body", BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, outlookMailItem, new object [] {});
    if (bodyObject == null) throw new ApplicationException (StringsManager.GetString("Cannot get outlook body property."));

    System.Type bodyType = bodyObject.GetType ();
    if (bodyType == null) throw new ApplicationException (StringsManager.GetString("Cannot get outlook body property type."));
    */

    foreach (string s in attachments)
      attachmentsType.InvokeMember ("Add", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, attachmentsObject, new object [] {s, olByValue, ++bodyLength, s});
  }
}
#endregion

#region private members

private System.Type outlookType         = null;
private object      outlookObject       = null;
private object      namespaceMAPI       = null;
private System.Type namespaceMAPIType   = null;
object              outlookMailItem     = null;
System.Type         outlookMailItemType = null;

private const int olFolderDeleted   = 3;
private const int olFolderOutbox    = 4;
private const int olFolderSentItems = 5; 
private const int olFolderInbox     = 6; 
private const int olFolderCalendar  = 9; 
private const int olFolderContacts  = 10; 
private const int olFolderJournal   = 11; 
private const int olFolderNotes     = 12; 
private const int olFolderTasks     = 13; 
private const int olFolderDrafts    = 16; 

private const int olByValue      = 1;
private const int olByReference  = 4;
private const int olEmbeddeditem = 5;

#endregion
}
}
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far (eg: _add some code, screenShots, ..._)

Comment: Also, try to formulate a question (this is a Q&A site after all)

Comment: OK, we know now that your app crashes, but you haven't asked any question.

Comment: Issue is in sending file.Rest of the cases like sending simple text msg is fine.
Need to know what addition to be done to make compatible for outlook 2010 explicilty.How do i know the cause for the crash.
It crashes at "outlookObject = Activator.CreateInstance (outlookType);",when outlook open.
outlookObject = Activator.CreateInstance (outlookType);
Error message: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem...go to properties(of outlook)..compatibility...select any of the older versions  My application worked with XP service pack 3 compatibilty.
Thank god...I wadted so much time in finding error details... but finally..this simple thing troubled me for 4-5 days..guys save time by using this one as your primary investigation,if you have similar issue...good luck